# Nested flexbox equal height columns broken in Google Chrome

Tags: html, css, sass, flexbox

I want a number of sidebar blocks to be spaced evenly throughout a long post.

To achieve this I'm using Flexbox within the sidebar to handle the even spacing of the blocks. This works perfectly.

Code Pen: http://codepen.io/jameswilson/pen/yyOLaz?editors=110

**UPDATE:  A working solution has been found, see Slawa Eremkin's answer below for details!**

**Working Code Pen: http://codepen.io/jameswilson/pen/xbVVLL?editors=110**

When I go to set the equal column heights using a standard Equal Height column procedure with Flexbox,  it only works in Firefox, not Chrome.

In Chrome, the only workaround I can come up with is to use an equal-height javascript fallback to manually set the height of the sidebar container to a fixed pixel height matching that of the main column.

Is there some magic that I'm missing about making this work in Chrome?

**NOTE: I don't have the luxury of changing the HTML structure, so an ideal solution would be CSS only based on the structure provided in the Codepen.**

[image: Firefox]

[image: Google Chrome]

**HTML:**

```
<div class="l-container">
  <div class="l-prefix">
    <div class="l-prefix-inner">
      <p>This is a prefix column that spans the full width of the container. This block prevents properly using <code>display:table</code> to achieve equal height columns of the two regions below.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="l-main">
    <div class="l-main-inner">
      <p>Bacon ipsum dolor amet shoulder rump sirloin kevin picanha corned beef landjaeger, ball tip cow swine short ribs turkey alcatra pancetta bresaola. Porchetta sausage doner, jowl pig filet mignon corned beef spare ribs shank. Pig chuck swine, filet mignon pork salami shankle cupim porchetta hamburger capicola landjaeger sirloin ribeye. Filet mignon drumstick sirloin salami, ham hock tongue bacon. Pork meatball swine turducken.</p>
      <p>Landjaeger andouille leberkas kielbasa flank, kevin corned beef tail jerky tri-tip hamburger pork ham hock. Spare ribs ground round short ribs, brisket tri-tip sirloin ham hock pork pork belly chicken drumstick picanha corned beef. Prosciutto cow capicola fatback jerky doner cupim rump pork loin. Salami pork loin hamburger pastrami boudin. Short ribs shoulder biltong, jowl picanha cupim ribeye leberkas. Shankle ball tip drumstick capicola boudin. Jerky ribeye sirloin strip steak, shoulder tongue brisket.</p>
      <p>Chuck shank t-bone boudin meatloaf pork chop shankle tail leberkas capicola landjaeger tenderloin pork ball tip ribeye. Beef ribs capicola short loin salami, ground round frankfurter picanha chuck hamburger pancetta meatloaf tongue bacon turkey turducken. Beef short loin flank kielbasa boudin kevin capicola cupim jerky andouille doner. Doner sirloin short loin kielbasa strip steak.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="l-sidebar">
    <div class="l-sidebar-inner">
      <div class="block">
        Beef ribs.
      </div>
      <div class="block">
        Chuck shank.
      </div>
      <div class="block">
        Jerky ribeye.
      </div>
      <div class="block">
        Salami pork loin.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**And the SCSS:**

```
// Implement equal height columns
// on adjacent layout regions.
.l-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

// Implement vertically-spaced
// sidebar blocks.
.l-sidebar-inner {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.l-sidebar .block {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #6a6;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  &:last-of-type {
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
}

// Layout styles only below this point.
.l-container {
  width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.l-prefix {
  width: 600px;
  clear: both;
  float: left;
}
.l-main {
  width: 70%;
  float: left;
  background: #eea;
}
.l-sidebar {
  width: 30%;
  float: left;
  background: #aea;
}
.l-main-inner,
.l-prefix-inner {
  padding: 0 1em;
}
```

Comment: possible guidance: [Percentage height not working in nested flexbox layout in Chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31046621/3597276)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Checkout my codepen: http://codepen.io/slawaEremin/pen/wBGBrj

The main idea is to use `display: flex` for the direct child (.l-sidebar) of the parent block (.l-container) and to use `flex-basis: 100%` instead of `height: 100%` in .l-sidebar-inner because Chrome doesn't understand the height: 100%;

```
.l-sidebar {
  display: flex;
}
.l-sidebar-inner {
  flex-basis: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Comment: just make another update with only css changes, maybe it will help you http://codepen.io/slawaEremin/pen/wBGBrj

Comment: Alright! This is the best approximation to the actual correct solution. For the record the correct solution was to simply add `.l-sidebar {display: flex;}` and replace `.l-sidebar-inner { height: 100%; }` with `.l-sidebar-inner { flex-basis: 100%; }`.

Comment: I created a cleaned up version of your codepen with the basic changes needed.  Note there were a few extra styles moved around that I reverted to how it was in the original pen:  http://codepen.io/jameswilson/pen/xbVVLL?editors=110

Answer (score 1):

I moved the `.l-sidebar-inner` into the same div as the `.l-main-inner` and played with the nesting. It seems to be working for me in both now.

Here's my updated [codepen](http://codepen.io/fishgraphics/pen/ZYWQog)

Comment: I believe you missed the note about not being able to change the html structure.

Comment: You are correct, I didn't see that note. I guess I read through it too fast. None the less, Here's an [updated codepen](http://codepen.io/fishgraphics/pen/gbrrKy) where your original HTML is untouched, and everything still seems to be working in both browsers.

Comment: Thanks for the update. This is a good effort and a valid solution. However, I was unable to use the `flex: 1` and `flex: 2` to define the column widths due to the need to also support legacy code which depends on floated grid column layouts, therefore I have to stick with the current solution from Slawa as the accepted answer.  You might also want to update your solution to describe the differences between my original pen and your pen.