# Percentage height not working in nested flexbox layout in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, flexbox

I have a following layout fully working in Firefox and IE:
[image: Firefox]

Unfortunately it is quite broken in Chrome, namely the dark blue container is collapsed even though it has height 100% of its parent:
[image: Chrome]

I tried [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27412929/nested-flexbox-equal-height-columns-broken-in-google-chrome), but without any luck. Any ideas how to fix this on Chrome without breaking it in other browsers?

```css
html,
body {
  height: 97%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

div {
  border: 10px dotted teal;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  border-color: tomato;
  height: 100%;
}

.row {
  flex-flow: row;
}

.column {
  flex-flow: column;
}

.item1 {
  flex: 1;
}

.item2 {
  flex: 2;
}

.item3 {
  flex: 3;
}

.c1 {
  border-color: gold;
}

.c2 {
  border-color: darkblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item3">
    <div class="container column c2">
      <div class="item1 c1"></div>
      <div class="item3"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item1 c1"></div>
  <div class="item2"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The question says:

> I have a following layout fully working in Firefox and IE.
>   Unfortunately it is broken in Chrome, namely the dark blue
>   container is collapsed even though it has height 100% of its parent.

Actually, an argument could be made that the opposite is true: Chrome has it right, while Firefox and IE are "broken".

*First, here's the solution:*

```
.item3 { height: 100%; }
```

Now let's look at your document structure and the heights applied:

```
<html> <!-- height: 97% -->
<body> <!-- height: 97% -->
<div class="container"> <!-- height: 100%; -->
    <div class="item3"> <!-- height: ?? -->
        <div class="container column c2"> <!-- height: 100% ; this is the collapsed box -->
                       ...
                       ...
                       ...
```

As per the [CSS specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#the-height-property), when using percentages to set the `height` of an element (like you are doing with `.container`), the parent element *must* also have an explicit height. In reference to your collapsed `div`, its parent (`.item3`) does not have a defined height.

From the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#the-height-property):

> **<percentage>**
> The percentage is calculated with respect to the height
>   of the generated box's containing block. If the height of the
>   containing block is not specified explicitly (i.e., it depends on
>   content height), and this element is not absolutely positioned, the
>   value computes to 'auto'.
>
> **auto**
> The height depends on the values of other properties.

In terms of the `height` property, it would appear from this example that Chrome defines "containing block" as "parent", while Firefox and IE define "containing block" as "ancestor", or they respect flex heights as a reference for percentage heights.

Hence, since the `div` with the dark blue border (`.container column c2`) has no content, and its  parent has no specified height, then there is no height and the box collapses in Chrome.

However, by specifying a height for `.item3`, which is the parent of the collapsed box, the height works on all browsers.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/efz4repu/1/)

---

**UPDATE**

More details:

- [Heights rendering differently in Chrome and Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35537510/3597276)

Comment: Oh, I entirely forgot about this question (shame on me), I already got it solved in Angular Material ticket on GitHub. However I believe this will help some other people as well (or possible the future me). Thank you for a thorough answer.

Answer (score 0):

you missed to mention height of .item3 class in percentage, we should make sure parent should have height in percentage unit then only child height in percentage will work.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 97%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

div {
  border: 10px dotted teal;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  border-color: tomato;
  height: 100%;
}

.row {
  flex-flow: row;
}

.column {
  flex-flow: column;
}

.item1 {
  flex: 1;
}

.item2 {
  flex: 2;
}

.item3 {
  flex: 3;
  height: 100%;
}

.c1 {
  border-color: gold;
}

.c2 {
  border-color: darkblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item3">
    <div class="container column c2">
      <div class="item1 c1"></div>
      <div class="item3"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item1 c1"></div>
  <div class="item2"></div>
</div>
```